# Getting Ghost in Milwaukee Junction

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

So I'm trying to get the ghost award on Milwaukee Junction. I can get through the whole map with 0 takedowns, 0 suspicious cameras and 0 alerted guards. And I can talk Zeke down and save Josie. But I still don't get Ghost. I've watched GreasedScotsman's walk-through and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I have this feeling it's that helicopter buzzing around on the roof...

Any ideas?

Comment: I got Ghost in Milwaukee Junction earlier today. The helicopter is definitely not the answer. Did you, by chance, get shot at by the turret?

Comment: You also may have actually got it and just missed the pop-up. It scrolls by fairly quickly.

Comment: In the walk through I saw, the pop up comes up after Zeke escapes, I was looking closely all 4 times I did the level trying to get it. And no, I wasn't shot (or even noticed) by the turret. The only shots fired the whole level was some guy in a lab letting off a few shots, but it didn't go hostile...

Comment: @Coomie Did you get the ghost bonus for entering the plant?

Comment: @mordi2k No, I didn't get any ghosts. I don't know what I did wrong, it never went hostile or even alert and between the start of the level and the first ghost there are only 4 guys!

Comment: Not sure what to say here. The first ghost is simply unmissable if you silent takedown the first guy, then climb up the crates to the roof access. Anyway glad you got it on your second try.

Comment: @JamesJiao I know, right and you don't even need to take him down. I did that part of the level 10 times without getting noticed and never got ghost - hence the "glitch in the matrix" line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have been a glitch in the matrix. I started the game over again and got ghosts all the way through.